# Using LINQ to group a list of objects

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, linq-to-objects

I have an object:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int GroupID { get; set; }
}
```

I return a list that may look like the following:

```
List<Customer> CustomerList = new List<Customer>();
CustomerList.Add( new Customer { ID = 1, Name = "One", GroupID = 1 } );
CustomerList.Add( new Customer { ID = 2, Name = "Two", GroupID = 1 } );
CustomerList.Add( new Customer { ID = 3, Name = "Three", GroupID = 2 } );
CustomerList.Add( new Customer { ID = 4, Name = "Four", GroupID = 1 } );
CustomerList.Add( new Customer { ID = 5, Name = "Five", GroupID = 3 } );
CustomerList.Add( new Customer { ID = 6, Name = "Six", GroupID = 3 } );
```

I want to return a linq query which will look like

```
CustomerList
  GroupID =1
    UserID = 1, UserName = "UserOne", GroupID = 1
    UserID = 2, UserName = "UserTwo", GroupID = 1
    UserID = 4, UserName = "UserFour", GroupID = 1
  GroupID =2
    UserID = 3, UserName = "UserThree", GroupID = 2
  GroupID =3
    UserID = 5, UserName = "UserFive", GroupID = 3
    UserID = 6, UserName = "UserSix",
```

I tried from

[Using Linq to group a list of objects into a new grouped list of list of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697253/using-linq-to-group-a-list-of-objects-into-a-new-grouped-list-of-list-of-objects)

code

```
var groupedCustomerList = CustomerList
  .GroupBy(u => u.GroupID)
  .Select(grp => grp.ToList())
  .ToList();
```

works but does not give the desired output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Linq to group a list of objects into a new grouped list of list of objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697253/using-linq-to-group-a-list-of-objects-into-a-new-grouped-list-of-list-of-objects)

Answer (score 86):

```
var groupedCustomerList = CustomerList.GroupBy(u => u.GroupID)
                                      .Select(grp =>new { GroupID =grp.Key, CustomerList = grp.ToList()})
                                      .ToList();
```

Comment: If it helped you (as it helped me), select this as answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
var groupedCustomerList = CustomerList
                         .GroupBy(u => u.GroupID, u=>{
                                                        u.Name = "User" + u.Name;
                                                        return u;
                                                     }, (key,g)=>g.ToList())
                         .ToList();
```

If you don't want to change the original data, you should add some method (kind of clone and modify) to your class like this:

```
public class Customer {
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int GroupID { get; set; }
  public Customer CloneWithNamePrepend(string prepend){
    return new Customer(){
          ID = this.ID,
          Name = prepend + this.Name,
          GroupID = this.GroupID
     };
  }
}    
//Then
var groupedCustomerList = CustomerList
                         .GroupBy(u => u.GroupID, u=>u.CloneWithNamePrepend("User"), (key,g)=>g.ToList())
                         .ToList();
```

I think you may want to **display** the `Customer` differently without modifying the original data. If so you should **design** your class `Customer` differently, like this:

```
public class Customer {
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int GroupID { get; set; }
  public string Prefix {get;set;}
  public string FullName {
    get { return Prefix + Name;}
  }            
}
//then to display the fullname, just get the customer.FullName; 
//You can also try adding some override of ToString() to your class

var groupedCustomerList = CustomerList
                         .GroupBy(u => {u.Prefix="User", return u.GroupID;} , (key,g)=>g.ToList())
                         .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

is this what you want?

```
var grouped = CustomerList.GroupBy(m => m.GroupID).Select((n) => new { GroupId = n.Key, Items = n.ToList() });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = from cx in CustomerList
         group cx by cx.GroupID into cxGroup
     orderby cxGroup.Key
     select cxGroup; 

foreach (var cxGroup in result) { 
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("GroupID = {0}", cxGroup.Key)); 
  foreach (var cx in cxGroup) { 
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("\tUserID = {0}, UserName = {1}, GroupID = {2}", 
      new object[] { cx.ID, cx.Name, cx.GroupID })); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The desired result can be obtained using [IGrouping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344977.aspx), which represents a collection of objects that have a common key in this case a `GroupID`

```
 var newCustomerList = CustomerList.GroupBy(u => u.GroupID)
                                                  .Select(group => new { GroupID = group.Key, Customers = group.ToList() })
                                                  .ToList();
```