# Get the number of distinct property values in List<T> using LINQ in C#

Tags: c#, linq, list, group-by, distinct

In a list `List<MyClass> ListOfMyClasses`, how can one get the how many distinct `GroupId` property values there are using LINQ?

```
public class MyClass
{
     public int GroupId;
}
```

For example let's say we have this list:

```
ListOfMyClasses: {MyClass1 (GroupId = 1), MyClass2 (GroupId = 3), MyClass3 (GroupId = 1)}
```

Here we should get the result as 2 (Two distinct numbers for GroupId).

Comment: Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18565004/using-linq-to-group-a-list-of-objects) SO question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is one way to do it using `Distinct`:

```
ListOfMyClasses.Select(t => t.GroupId).Distinct().Count()
```

Or you can also use `GroupBy`:

```
ListOfMyClasses.GroupBy(t => t.GroupId).Count()
```

Answer (score 4):

This should work for you.

```
var result = list.Select(x => x.GroupId).Distinct().Count();
```

First you are selecting out all the `GroupId`s. Then you are filtering them to be distinct. Finally you are getting the count of those values.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, just want to share some extension which I use in all my projects and it also solves your task

```
public class EqualityComparer<TEntity, TProperty>: IEqualityComparer<TEntity>
{
    private readonly Func<TEntity, TProperty> _property;

    public EqualityComparer(Func<TEntity, TProperty> property)
    {
        _property = property;
    }

    public bool Equals(TEntity x, TEntity y)
    {
        return _property(x).Equals(_property.Invoke(y));
    }

    public int GetHashCode(TEntity obj)
    {
        return _property(obj).GetHashCode();
    }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> DistinctByProperty<T, TProp>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, TProp> propertyFunc)
    {
        return source.Distinct(new EqualityComparer<T, TProp>(propertyFunc));
    }
}
```

It allows you to write `ListOfMyClasses.DistinctByProperty(x => x.GroupId).Count()`