# Create string with Objects grouped by same Property

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class with the following properties:

```
public class Party
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and this method to populate the list:

```
List<Party> parties = new List<Party>();
parties.Add(new Party {Type = "Plaintiff", Name = "Eilean Dover"});
parties.Add(new Party {Type = "Plaintiff", Name = "Bea O'Problem"});
parties.Add(new Party {Type = "Defendant", Name = "Anna Graham"});
parties.Add(new Party {Type = "Witness", Name = "John Doe"});
parties.Add(new Party {Type = "Witness", Name = "Rosa Shore"});
```

My goal is to put all the objects (parties) in a single string.
So far, I have used String.Join and Linq in order to put them inline.

```
string partiesinline = string.Join(", ", parties.Select(x => String.Join(" ", new[] { x.Type, x.Name })));
```

After running this, the string `partiesinline` looks like this:

```
Plaintiff Eilean Dover, Plaintiff Bea O'Problem, Defendant Anna Graham, Witness John Doe, Witness Rosa Shore
```

My futher improvement is to group the parties by their type and put the type in a plural form if there are more of the same type.
Ideally, the string should look like this:

```
Plaintiffs Eilean Dover, Bea O'Problem, Defendant Anna Graham and Witnesses John Doe, Rosa Shore
```

I could be using a Dictionary or a List in order to get the plurar of the Type but I am stuck in grouping the parties and retaining in the partiesinline string a single type for the parties having the same name.
Do you have any suggestions with explanation?

I have read [Using LINQ to group a list of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18565004/using-linq-to-group-a-list-of-objects) and [Using Linq to group a list of objects into a new grouped list of list of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697253/using-linq-to-group-a-list-of-objects-into-a-new-grouped-list-of-list-of-objects) but I am stuck, I am unable to identify the steps in order to get the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need multiple calls to `string.Join`. Consider:

1. you want to combine the individual names for each group into one string per group,
2. and then you want to combine the strings generated from each group into a single string.

The `GroupBy` method has an overload which lets you specify not just what you're grouping by:

```
party => party.Type
```

but the intermediate result for each group; in this case, a single string:

```
(type, group) => $"{type} {String.Join(", ", group.Select(party => party.Name))}"
```

- `type` is what each group is grouped on (in this case the value in the `Type` property)
- `group` is the grouped instances of `Party`, whose `Name` property we can project to a sequence of strings (`group.Select(party => party.Name`), which we can then join into a single string using `String.Join`.

Altogether:

```
var grouping = parties.GroupBy(
    party => party.Type,
    (type, group) => $"{type} {String.Join(", ", group.Select(party => party.Name))}"
);
```

`grouping` can now provide us with a sequence of strings, which we can use again with `String.Join` to create a single string:

```
var result = string.Join(",", grouping);
```

---

As for pluralizing the type, I think you could generally add an `s`, but put the exceptions to this rule inside a `Dictionary<string, string>`:

```
private static Dictionary<string, string> specialPlurals = new Dictionary<string, string> {
    {"Witness", "Witnesses"}
};
```

Then, write a function that would give you the appropriate plural:

```
public static string Pluralize(string singular) {
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(singular)) { return singular;}
    if (specialPlurals.TryGetValue(singular, out var plural)) { return plural;}
    return $"{singular}s";
}
```

and use it as follows:

```
var grouping = parties.GroupBy(
    party => party.Type,
    (type, group) => $"{Pluralize(type)}: {String.Join(", ", group.Select(party => party.Name))}"
);
var result = string.Join("; ", grouping);
```

This generates the following:

```
Plaintiffs: Eilean Dover, Bea O'Problem; Defendants: Anna Graham; Witnesses: John Doe, Rosa Shore
```

[.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kbDIUC)

Comment: Although the answer Jamiec provided was enough for my tests, yours has the steps detailed and it is good documentation for further use. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Given a dictionary where you can look up plurals:

```
Dictionary<string,string> plurals = new Dictionary<string,string>{
    ["Plaintiff"] = "Plaintiffs",
    ["Defendant"] = "Defendants",
    ["Witness"] = "Witnesses"
};
```

You could use this code:

```
var result = string.Join(", ", parties.GroupBy(x => x.Type).Select(item => {
    var prefix = item.Count()>1 ? plurals[item.Key] : item.Key;
    var people = String.Join(", ", item.Select(x => x.Name));
    return $"{prefix} {people}";
}));
```

Live example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/wCVgeB