# How to split elements of the group in many lists?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a a list (OriginalList) with elements of type MyType. My Type is:

```
MyType
{
    long IDReferenceElement;
    long IDElement;
    string value;
}
```

So I would like to separate in lists each group of elements, where each group has the elements with the same IDReferenceElement.

For example, a list of lists, each list of the main list has only the elements of the same group.

```
List<List<MyType>>
```

An example, I have a original list with this elements:

- Item1(1,1,1);
- Item2(1,2,2);
- Item3(1,3,3);
- Item4(2,4,4);
- Item5(2,5,5);
- Item6(2,6,6);
- Item7(3,7,7);
- Item8(3,8,8);
- Item9(3,9,9);

I would like to get three lists:

List1 with the items:
- Item1(1,1,1);
- Item2(1,2,2);
- Item3(1,3,3);

List2:
- Item4(2,4,4);
- Item5(2,5,5);
- Item6(2,6,6);

List3:
- Item7(3,7,7);
- Item8(3,8,8);
- Item9(3,9,9);

To get it, I am trying something like that:

```
List<List>> myResultList = myOriginalList.GroupBy(x=>x.IDReferenceElement).ToList();
```

It does not work, because a group element is not a list. I would like to know how to access each group of the grouping and to covert to a list.

Thanks so much.

Comment: Duplicate :-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697253/using-linq-to-group-a-list-of-objects-into-a-new-grouped-list-of-list-of-objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<List<MyType>> myResultList = 
      myOriginalList.GroupBy(x=>x.IDReferenceElement)
                    .Select(gr=>gr.ToList()) // convert each group into List
                    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to use a lookup

```
var myResultsLookup = myOriginalList.ToLookup(myType => myType.IDReferenceElement);
```

Now each subset of data can be accessed using the IDReferenceElement value as the key

```
var results = myResultsLookup[1];
```

using your test data results will contain the elements (1,1,"1"), (1,2,"2") and (1,3,"3")