# Breaking up a list into a set of indexed lists

Tags: c#, linq, list, dictionary

I have a list of instances of a class like this.

```
public class Customer
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public Guid StoreId { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I need to break it up by the stores so that I have a set of lists, where each list contains all the customers belonging to the same store. I've tried [grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2697280/1525840) but that produces just a list of lists. I've tried dictionaries but that gave me `Dictionary<Guid, Customer>`, when I need something like `Dictionary<Guid, List<Customer>>`. I tried looking at `ILookup` and even something called `SortedDictionary`.

In the end I got confused and wimzy.

I'd like to be able to perform an iteration like this.

```
foreach(KeyValuePair storeWithCustomers in brokenUpList)
{
  DoSomething(storeWithCustomers.Key);
  foreach(Customer customer in storeWithCustomers)
    DoSomething(customer.Name);
}
```

It doesn't have to be `KeyValuePair`, of course, and the breaking up of the list doesn't have to be `ToDictionary` (although it may, if it's a good solution).

Comment: You want a set of lists, but a list of lists isn't ok? What?

Comment: How does `GroupBy` not give you exactly what you need? The results from that line up perfectly with what you're saying you want to do with it.

Comment: In the linked answer, the `Select` statement throws away the grouping information and returns a list of lists.  Using `GroupBy` is what you want.

Comment: Thanks @BJMyers that clears it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, you just need to `.GroupBy` like this:

```
foreach(var group in customers.GroupBy(x=>x.StoreId))
{
  DoSomething(group.Key);
  foreach(var customer in group)
    DoSomething(customer.Name);
}
```

Comment: @Got it! Really well put! I've taken the liberty to paste that in your answer, because I'd definitely find that helpful if I was researching and hit this question. Feel free to flag this comment as obso.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`ToDictionary<TSource, TKey>` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549277(v=vs.110).aspx) after you call `GroupBy` to select the grouped results into the `Dictionary` of the desired type.

Note that the method takes two (lambda) parameters (well, the particular overload used here, at least).  The first is a selector that defines the keys (and implicitly, their type), and the second defines the values (implicitly defining their type as well).

As shown in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34954644/1187982), the `GroupBy` method will return `IEnumerable<IGrouping<Guid,Customer>>`, which you can iterate over directly, like so:

```
foreach (IGrouping<Guid, Customer> grp in customers.GroupBy(obj => obj.StoreId))
{
    Guid storeID = grp.Key;
    IEnumerable<Customer> customerCollection = grp;
    foreach (Customer customer in customerCollection)
    {
        // Insert code here.
    }
}
```

The above is likely the *better* approach (e.g. if your collection is lazily evaluated, it will probably retain that), but if that isn't an issue for you, the solution below will give you *exactly* what you asked for.

In the example below, the only line you're probably interested in is the *last* one.  The other code is merely to facilitate running it quickly in something like LinqPad to preview the results.

```
// Just populating some sample data.
List<Guid> storeIDs = new List<Guid>
{
    Guid.NewGuid(),
    Guid.NewGuid(),
    Guid.NewGuid(),
};
List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();

customers.Add(new Customer { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), StoreId = storeIDs[0], Name = "John" });
customers.Add(new Customer { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), StoreId = storeIDs[1], Name = "Jacob" });
customers.Add(new Customer { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), StoreId = storeIDs[2], Name = "Schmidt" });
customers.Add(new Customer { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), StoreId = storeIDs[0], Name = "May" });
customers.Add(new Customer { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), StoreId = storeIDs[1], Name = "Naomi" });
customers.Add(new Customer { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), StoreId = storeIDs[2], Name = "Tou" });

// Use the GroupBy method to group the customers by the StoreID
// Then, select the grouped data into a Dictionary.
// Use the StoreID as the key
// To make TValue a List<Customer> call ToList on the IGrouping.
Dictionary<Guid, List<Customer>> result = customers.GroupBy(obj => obj.StoreId).ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.ToList());
```