# Using Linq to group a list of objects that contains primitives data into a new grouped list of objects

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have a list of objects that contains different primitive data types:

```
List<object> list = new List<object>() { 
  3, "cat", 4.1, 'a', 5, "dog", "horse", 9.1, 'd', 1 
};
```

I want to be able to run a Linq query on the above list that groups all the element by data type and order as (string, integer,double,character) (if that makes sense?). Something like:

```
list = { "cat","dog", "horse", 3, 5, 1, 4.1, 9.1, 'a', 'd' }
```

I tried from

[Using Linq to group a list of objects into a new grouped list of list of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697253/using-linq-to-group-a-list-of-objects-into-a-new-grouped-list-of-list-of-objects)

code

```
lst
  .GroupBy(x => x.GetType())
  .Select(grp => grp.ToList())
  .ToList()
  .ForEach(group => group.ForEach(item => Console.WriteLine(item)));
```

works but does not give the desired output.

output

```
 { 3, 5, 1, "cat","dog", "horse",4.1, 9.1, 'a', 'd' }
```

Comment: Your expression works in general, which output do you want? Maybe just order by type?

Comment: Basically you want to aggregate your lists into one list. Of course the ForEach shows you that you have the correct gist of it.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski i want to reorder the output as (string,integer,double,character) not like (integer , string, double , character)

Comment: So you need to use a custom comparer and use `Sort`

Comment: If (string,integer,double,character) are sorted by type name descending on purpose, `list.OrderByDescending(x => x.GetType().Name)` should do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just order type name by descending after `Select`, it'll give you the desired output - (string, integer, double, character) items

```cs
list.GroupBy(x => x.GetType())
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Key.Name)
    .Select(grp => grp.ToList())
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(group => group.ForEach(Console.WriteLine));
```

Another option is order by [`IsPrimitive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isprimitive?view=netframework-4.8) property `OrderBy(g => g.Key.IsPrimitive)`, for your particular data it also gives the desired output

Answer (score 2):

If the problem is the order of the types in output, you could use a custom `IComparer` class and `Sort` you list.

The basic principle is you can map types to an integer score, and then return the comparison between the scores.

See [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.comparer-1?view=netframework-4.8).

([dotnetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/LT4MFJ) )

```
public class StringThenIntThenDoubleThenChar  : Comparer<object> 
{
    public override int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        return GetTypeScore(x).CompareTo(GetTypeScore(y));
    }

    private int GetTypeScore(object o) 
    {
        var type = o.GetType();
        if (type == typeof(string)) return 0;
        else if (type == typeof(int)) return 1;
        else if (type == typeof(double)) return 2;
        else if (type == typeof(char)) return 3;
        else return 4;

        /* Or, if you are using C# 8 :
        return o.GetType() switch
        {
            Type t when t == typeof(string) => 0,
            Type t when t == typeof(int) => 1,
            Type t when t == typeof(double) => 2,
            Type t when t == typeof(char) => 3,
            _ => 4
        };
        */
    }
}
```

Use it like this :

```
        List<object> list = new List<object>() { 3, "cat", 4.1, 'a', 5, "dog", "horse", 9.1, 'd', 1 };

        list.Sort(new StringThenIntThenDoubleThenChar());
        list.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

The advantage over the simpler solution already given (sort by type name) is that you can customize it as you wish.

You can also refine the comparer, for instance if scores are equal, you can then compare them using their default comparison order (so that the `string`, `int` etc. are respectively sorted among them).

Answer (score 2):

Similar approach to [@Pac0's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61285958/using-linq-to-group-a-list-of-objects-that-contains-primitives-data-into-a-new-g/61286181#61286181) answer, you could create a method to decide the sorting order on types:

```
private static int OrderByOnType(object o)
{
    var type = o.GetType();

    if (type == typeof(string))
        return 0;

    else if (type == typeof(int)) 
        return 1;

    else if (type == typeof(double)) 
        return 2;

    else if (type == typeof(char)) 
        return 3;

    return 4;
}
```

Then pass this method to [`Enumerable.OrderBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netframework-4.8) from LINQ to create a new sorted list:

```
var result = list.OrderBy(OrderByOnType);

Console.WriteLine("{ " + string.Join(", ", result) + " }");
```

Or sort the original list in-place with [`List<T>.Sort`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=netframework-4.8) by passing your own [`Comparison<T> Delegate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.comparison-1?view=netframework-4.8):

```
list.Sort((x, y) => OrderByOnType(x).CompareTo(OrderByOnType(y)));

Console.WriteLine("{ " + string.Join(", ", list) + " }");
```

Which can also be wrapped into a separate method:

```
private static int CompareTwoTypes(object x, object y)
{
    return OrderByOnType(x).CompareTo(OrderByOnType(y));
}

list.Sort(CompareTwoTypes);

Console.WriteLine("{ " + string.Join(", ", list) + " }");
```

All of which give:

```
{ cat, dog, horse, 3, 5, 1, 4.1, 9.1, a, d }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the shorter version of [@Pac0's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61285958/using-linq-to-group-a-list-of-objects-that-contains-primitives-data-into-a-new-g/61286181#61286181) and [@RoadRunner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5238915/roadrunner) answer is to use switch Expression in Linq query.

```
        list.OrderBy(x => x  switch
        {
             string xString=> 0,
             int xInt=> 1,
             double xDouble=> 2,
             char xChar=> 3,
            _ => -1,
        }).ToList().ForEach(item => Console.WriteLine(item));
```